# What are C based Services and Java based Services?

Tags: java, c, android

What are C based services and Java based services in Android? What is similarity and dissimilarity between them ? 
Are C based services available in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System C-library is a BSD-derived implementation of the standard C system library (libc), tuned for embedded Linux-based devices. Meaning, this is the operating system (ref "What is Android?".

The Application framework is written in Java, and it is these frameworks you as a programmer mostly use. Here you have ActivityManager and ContentProvider to work with.

More to read: [What is Android?](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html)